# Relaying oauth2 tokens with Spring Cloud Feign

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to use the `@EnableOAuth2Sso` along with `@EnableResourceServer` annotation to relay in coming `Authorization` tokens to upstream services.  I can't seem to configure it properly.  I don't want or need to really configure the internal oauth2 client to retrieve a token, it should *always* pull the token from the incoming request.  Is this possible to do?